# SQLAlchemy on demand collection loading on result set containing more than one item

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Given I have two models (A and B), with one to many relationship between them, is there a way in SQLAlchemy to first retrieve list of models A (possibly filtered out somehow):

```
resultsA = session.query(A).filter(company_id=3).all()
```

... and then load each of model B related to each model A in resulting query set in a fashion (and this is crucial!) that doesn't fire *n* number of SQL queries (where *n* is number of A models in resultsA result set)?

Comment: Get all the ids of model B instances, then perform a `SELECT * FROM ... WHERE id IN ...` query.

Comment: Obviously, but this won't populate relationship attribute on each of A models in result set, and that's what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import joinedload

results_A = (session.query(A)
        .filter(A.company_id==3)
        .options(joinedload(A.your_relation_to_B_field))
        .all()) # will load all related B objects in one query
results_B_0 = results_A[0].your_relation_to_B_field #won't trigger sql
```

Or (equivalent, but with explicit join):

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import contains_eager

results_A = (session.query(A)
        .outerjoin(A.your_relation_to_B_field)
        .filter(A.company_id==3)
        .options(contains_eager(A.your_relation_to_B_field))
        .all()) # will load all related B objects in one query
results_B_0 = results_A[0].your_relation_to_B_field #won't trigger sql
```

Use `join` instead of `outerjoin` in second example if you don't want to load A objects if they don't have B objects.

If you didn't explicitly set `your_relation_to_B_field` relation to A from B, then this will be name, specified in backref (or back_populates) option in your relation in B to A.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest `subqueryload`. If you are always going to use the models in this manner go ahead and set the lazy attribute on the relation `relationship("modelb", lazy="subquery")`

If you don't always want it to operate that way (for example, you use model A in various ways), then you can set the option on the query at the time.

Given classes `ModelA` and `ModelB` defined and ModelA has relationship to ModelB called "modelb_items"

```
query = session.query(ModelA).filter(ModelA.stuff == 'GoodStuff').options(subqueryload(ModelA.modelb_items))
for a in query: # fires single sql SELECT to get ModelA items
    print a.name

    # fires single sql SELECT to get ALL related ModelB items.
    for item in a.modelb_items: 
        print item.modelb_property
```

The important thing to understand here is that *only 2 SQL SELECT statements execute ever*.

If you wrap the items loop in an if statement that never executes, only the first SQL SELECT executes. No matter how many model A objects you have, the second select, even though it's in the loop, only executes once. As the other answer indicates, you can do joinedload, but that has other issues (such as adding an extra outerjoin). You can use either it depends on your needs.